# How to add turbine labels to a farm layout visualization in FLORIS?

Tags: python, matplotlib, floris

I am trying to add the turbine labels to the wind farm turbine plot created using FLORIS, but I am getting an error using the `add_turbine_id_labels` function. I have added an image of the plot I want to add turbine labels to. The line of code used to create the plot is:`visualization.plot_turbines_with_fi(fi=fi)`
[image: Turbine Plot]

This is the error I am getting:

```
visualization.plot_turbines_with_fi(fi=fi)
visualization.add_turbine_id_labels(fi=fi, ax=plt.Axes)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 2
      1 visualization.plot_turbines_with_fi(fi=fi)
----> 2 visualization.add_turbine_id_labels(fi=fi, ax=plt.Axes)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\floris\tools\visualization.py:140, in add_turbine_id_labels(fi, ax, **kwargs)
    134 layout_x, layout_y, _, _, _ = rotate_coordinates_rel_west(
    135     np.array([wind_direction]),
    136     coordinates_array
    137 )
    139 for i in range(fi.floris.farm.n_turbines):
--> 140     ax.annotate(
    141         i,
    142         (layout_x[0,0,i], layout_y[0,0,i]),
    143         xytext=(0,10),
    144         textcoords="offset points",
    145         **kwargs
    146     )

TypeError: annotate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xy'
```

Here is a [link](https://nrel.github.io/floris/_autosummary/floris.tools.visualization.add_turbine_id_labels.html#floris.tools.visualization.add_turbine_id_labels) to the relevant FLORIS info.

Please could someone let me know what I need to do to solve this error!

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

`plt.Axes` is a class, you need an instance object here.
Passing a class instead of an instance creates this ambiguous TypeError as the `self` object is not inserted as the first argument.

I am not familiar with the library you are using but with *raf's* clarification this seems indeed to be the intended way: you need to insert an `axis` object.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
visualization.plot_turbines_with_fi(fi=fi, ax=ax)
visualization.add_turbine_id_labels(fi=fi, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the intended use. @jackdoti please post this question in a new discussion in the floris github repository, and we’ll provide feedback along with examples. https://github.com/nrel/floris/discussions

Comment: @raf thank you I have now posted this in the discussions. https://github.com/NREL/floris/discussions/703